# splitting a sentences in to list of sentences by specific combinations

Tags: python

I have a sentence

```
string = 'senior engineer/developer in school/university'
```

my except output combinations are

```
string_list = ['senior engineer in school', 'senior engineer in university',
               'senior developer in school', 'senior developer in school]
```

I want to make a combination by splitting the sentence based on "/". Is there any option to split in such way? I was looking at itertools but its not the way i am expecting

```
x = string.split('/')
x = [y.split() for y in x]
print(list(combinations(x,len(x))))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) and clever splitting:

```
from itertools import product

list(map(' '.join, product(*(s.split('/') for s in string.split()))))
# ['senior engineer in school', 
#  'senior engineer in university', 
#  'senior developer in school', 
#  'senior developer in university']
```

This splits by space first and each token by slash second. `product` then builds all combinations from the resulting nested iterable. As those combinations are produced as `tuples`, we `' '.join` them back into sentences (`str`).